# Normalization/standardization: Should one do this before oversampling/undersampling the data or after?

Tags: machine-learning, oversampling

When working with imbalanced datasets, should one do one-hot encoding and data standardization before or after sampling techniques (such as oversampling or undersampling)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't play much of a difference but you should do most pre-processing steps (encoding, normalization/standardization, etc) **before** under/over-sampling the data.

This is because many sampling techniques require a simple model to be trained (e.g. [SMOTE](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) uses a [k-NN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) algorithm to generate samples, [ClusteringCentroids](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.ClusterCentroids.html) under-sampling technique involves [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) clustering). These models have better performance on pre-processed datasets (e.g. both k-NN and k-means use euclidean distance, which requires the data to be normalized).

So, in order for the sampling techniques to work best, you should previously perform any pre-processing steps you can. That being said, if you use a *random* over/under-sampler, I don't think it plays much of a difference.

Comment: "if you use a random over/under-sampler, I don't think it plays much of a difference."

This would be a good simulation study for someone out there to do