# Can I inverse the standardscaler after using SMOTE?

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, standardization, oversampling, smote

As it is written [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363312/normalization-standardization-should-one-do-this-before-oversampling-undersampl), you should standardize the data before applying SMOTE.
If I [inverse the standardscaler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552031/sklearnstandardscaler-can-i-inverse-the-standardscaler-for-the-model-output) action with `inverse_transform` after using  SMOTE, will it know how to inverse the synthesized observation?

Comment: "Correct" for what purpose?

Comment: Frank Harrell, a member on here and the founding chairman of the Biostat department at Vanderbilt, suggests not using SMOTE at all: https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: The SMOTE synthesizes new observations. Does the inverse_transform know how to inverse them?

Comment: According to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html, the scaling is simply a change of units of measurement.  I can't speak to what the software might "know," but changing the units back is simple.

Comment: But the SMOTE creates a new data point from the original point that was standardized. Could the inverse_transform command succeed inversing back a point that wasn't standardized by the StandardScaler?